# UTF-8 character change to two character

Tags: utf-8

In my text file, I used a character with value larger than 127 for example 0xDC. Then I loaded that text file in a device. Then I read that text file and that character. Then the character was changed to 0xC3 and 0x9C. How come it change to two character?

Thanks

Comment: It would really help if you tell us what device (and/or language) you're working with..

Comment: in which language do you read? normally you should explicitely say that you want to read UTF-8 or other encoding

Comment: its an embedded device use in the financial transaction. its just weird that the 0xDC will change to two byte character.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's the sequence for the character when encoded in UTF-8:

```
>>> '\xc3\x9c'.decode('utf-8')
u'\xdc'
```

Comment: Yeah exactly, but im wondering why  encoded to two byte character.

Comment: Because it's between 0x80 and 0x07ff. Below that encodes to 1 byte. Above that encodes to 3 or more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

[From wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

*"UTF-8 encodes each character (code point) in 1 to 4 octets (8-bit bytes), with the single octet encoding used only for the 128 US-ASCII characters."*